# RealityKit and ARKit – Specify Material Texture Application on Model

Tags: swift, textures, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Noob here. When using the following code, it wraps the image texture around the entire model. Is it possible to apply the image texture to a portion of the model (as opposed to the entire model itself) in RealityKit/ARKit?

**CODE:**

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()

material.baseColor = try! .texture(TextureResource.load(named: "image.jpg"))

modelSample?.model?.materials = [material]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply a texture to a portion of a AR model, not to an entire model, you have to UV-map this texture to a model in a 3d authoring tool (like 3dsMax, Maya, or Blender). UV-mapping is neither possible in RealityKit 1.0 nor in RealityKit 2.0.

Comment: Could you please look into this question and share your thought?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684317/how-to-take-a-picture-while-using-arkit

Comment: Hi @elk_cloner, read this post, please – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828300/arkit-on-different-iphones/66828695#66828695