# ARKit on different iPhones

Tags: sprite-kit, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I've been looking for an answer to whether ARKit, specifically ARSCNView, shows the same screen/view/scene size on all devices. I only have an iPhone XS so I am unable to test my ARKit app on other devices.

Currently I am overlaying it with an SKScene from SpriteKit, and in SpriteKit there are 2 different sizes all devices run on.

Through print statements I've been able to find that with the front-facing camera, thus presenting my face on-screen, and overlaying it with an SKScene, that the size of the screen/view/scene/etcetc is **375x812**.

Does anyone happen to know if all devices present the same size with ARKit + SpriteKit overlay?

Comment: Might I suggest my utility [Projector](https://github.com/aheze/Projector)? It's experimental, but simulates different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course different iPhone models present different resolutions. There's a big difference between iPhone's `screen size` and `viewport size`. Look at this table. In some cases `viewport size` is 1/9 of `screen size`, sometimes – 1/4. Though, some models have identical `screen size` and `viewport size`.

| Device | Screen Size | Viewport Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 12 Pro Max | 1284 x 2778 | 428 x 926 |
| iPhone X | 1125 x 2436 | 375 x 812 |
| iPhone SE 2 | 750 x 1334 | 375 x 667 |
| iPhone 8 Plus | 1080 x 1920 | 414 x 736 |
| iPhone 6s | 750 x 1334 | 375 x 667 |

For more details, you can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731258/arkit-viewport-size-vs-real-screen-resolution/60788960#60788960).

[This guide](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) gives you a visual representation.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the chart and link to the SO post, it was a very educational read! In short, the viewport basically renders a 1x screen? Am I correct to assume that? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @syds, simply put – yes.